# Fetch value from database as selected in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have a asp page in which i have a dropdown list. The complete list of values is binded in dropdown list from the database table "a". After selecting any value from that dropdown, i save it to database table "b". **Now, in 2nd asp page, i want to have that dropdown list with selected value from table "b".** 
My aspx page:

```
 <asp:DropDownList DataSource='<%# getBankTable() %>' ID="ddlBankName" DataValueField='BANK_ID'  
     DataTextField="BANK_DESC" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("BANK_ID") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
     runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

My .cs Page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        string sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Master LEFT JOIN BANK ON Master.BANK_ID = Transaction.BANK_ID";
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ddlBankName.Items.FindByValue(dr["BANK_ID"].ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
}
public void getBankTable()
{
    ddlBankName.Items.Clear();

    ddlBankName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", ""));
    clsDataAccess cls = new clsDataAccess();

    string sql = "SELECT BANK_ID,BANK_DESC FROM Master";

    DataTable dt = cls.GetDataTable(sql);

    ddlBankName.DataTextField = "BANK_DESC";
    ddlBankName.DataValueField = "BANK_ID";

    ddlBankName.DataSource = dt;
    ddlBankName.DataBind();
}
```

I am not able to do that. Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think it would be best to populate the Dropdown in your CS and set the value there as well.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBankName" DataValueField='BANK_ID' DataTextField="BANK_DESC" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

In your CS page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

 //Only fill it once on page load:
 if (!Page.IsPostBack) {

   getBankTable();

  string sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Master LEFT JOIN BANK ON Master.BANK_ID = Transaction.BANK_ID";
  OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  while (dr.Read()) {
      if (dr["BANK_ID"] != null)
      {
           ddlBankName.Items.FindByValue(dr["BANK_ID"].ToString()).Selected = true;
      }      
  }
 }
}

public void getBankTable() {
 ddlBankName.Items.Clear();

 ddlBankName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", ""));
 clsDataAccess cls = new clsDataAccess();

 string sql = "SELECT BANK_ID,BANK_DESC FROM Master";

 DataTable dt = cls.GetDataTable(sql);

 ddlBankName.DataTextField = "BANK_DESC";
 ddlBankName.DataValueField = "BANK_ID";

 ddlBankName.DataSource = dt;
 ddlBankName.DataBind();
}
```